# Javascript `new` keyword on function returning array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, new-operator

I was experimenting with the `new` keyword and I can't find an explanation for this behavior.
Let's say we have a function returning an integer:

(In firebug)

```
>>> function x() { return 2; }
>>> x()
2
>>> new x()
x { }
```

But if the function returns an array :

```
>>> function y() { return [2]; }
>>> y()
[2]
>>> new y()
[2]
```

Why is that ?

Comment: Off-topic: I know you're just experimenting, but it's worth getting in the habit early and if you're experimenting you may not (yet) know this:  The overwhelming convention in JavaScript code is that the names of constructor functions (functions you use with `new` rather than just calling directly) start with a capital letter, and the names of all other functions start with a lower-case letter. So `Foo` would be a constructor function, and `foo` would not.

Comment: Is this valid javascript? Why have you called x() on its own with no semi-colon?

Comment: @Pete2k: Looks like kbok is playing around in a JavaScript console. Also, semicolons are optional in JavaScript, statements can also be terminated by an EOL.

Comment: @Pete2k: Why should it not be valid? It's a function. Semi-colons are optional.

Comment: this is because I'm typing it in the firebug console.

Comment: your typing javascript live in firebug I didnt know you could do this. So is the [2] something that was returned (i.e. its not code itself)?

Comment: @Pete2k: Yup. You can do that in the console of Firebug, Chrome's dev tools, most others.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `new` operator has an interesting behavior: It returns the object created by the operator unless the constructor function returns a different object. Any non-object return value of the constructor function is ignored, which is why when you return `2` you don't see this.

Here's what happens when you say `new x()`:

1. The interpreter creates a new blank object.
2. It sets the object's underlying prototype to `x.prototype`.
3. It calls `x` with `this` set to the new object.
4. In the normal case, `x` doesn't return anything and the result of the `new` expression is the new object created in step 1. **But**, if `x` returns a non-`null` *object reference*, then that object reference is the result of the `new` expression rather than the object created in step 1. Any other kind of return value (`null`, primitive numbers, primitive strings, `undefined`, etc.) is ignored; it has to be a non-`null` object reference to take precedence over the object `new` created.

This special treatment given to object references by the `new` operator lets you substitute a different object for the one `new` created. This can be handy in some limited situations, but the *vast* majority of the time, a function designed to be used with `new` (called a *constructor function*) shouldn't return anything at all.

For some light reading (hah!), this is covered by [Section 13.2.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2) (*"[[Construct]]"*) of the specification ([HTML](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1); [PDF](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)), which is referenced by [Section 11.2.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2) (*"The `new` operator"*).

Comment: Link: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_13.2.2 :) Should we always do it that way? I provide a short summary and you go into the details? ;)

Comment: @Felix: Yeah, still deciding about that site, hence linking to the canonical spec at the ECMA. Beautifully done, though.

Answer (score 5):

Because an array is an object but `2` is not.

If you call a function with the `new` keyword, it has to return an object. If you don't do that explicitly, it automatically returns `this` (which is an empty object that inherits from `funcName.prototype)`.