# How can I build a virtual object cache?

Tags: javascript

I have a set of objects and I want to be able to use the same syntax to either

- build a new object or
- load an existing object.

I've built a "cache" that takes the object and the context that the object was created using and uses this data to see if the object has been previously created. So, for example, if I build `theObject = new myObject(param1, param2)`, the cache would save the object as `{ obj: theObject, context: { param1: param1, param2: param2 } }` and would be loaded again if I give it a context with the same values of `param1` and `param2`.

I thought I was being clever and would be able to build the object like this:

```
myObject = function(param1, param2) {
  var context = { param1: param1, param2: param2 };
  var cacheHit = this.cache.find(context);

  if (cacheHit) return cacheHit; // <-- Doesn't work :(

  this.param1 = param1;
  this.param2 = param2;
  this.cache.save(this, context);
};

myObject.prototype = { cache: new myCacheObject }; // Shared cache in all instances
```

Sadly, I've learned that the `new` keyword means that I cannot use a `return` statement. I'd like for the cache collections to be internalized so that it's possible to build similar objects without a built-in cache and they would work the same. However, I don't think that I can do this with the `new` keyword.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

**Update**:

It turns out that this approach actually does work and my problem was stemming from inheritance (particularly since this is JavaScript inheritance). When extending this object, I used the following syntax:

```
myObject = function(param1, param2) {
  if (arguments.length) {
     var context = { param1: param1, param2: param2 };
     var cacheHit = this.cache.find(context);

     if (cacheHit) return cacheHit;

     this.param1 = param1;
     this.param2 = param2;
     this.cache.save(this, context);
   }
};

// Extended from myObject
anotherObject = function(foo, bar) {
  // Call parent constructor
  myObject.call(this, foo, bar);
};

anotherObject.prototype = new myObject;
anotherObject.prototype.constructor = anotherObject;
```

Since calling the parent constructor can't force the child to return a value, the child has to explicitly denote this.

```
anotherObject = function(foo, bar) {
  return myObject.call(this, foo, bar);
};
```

Hopefully, I can come up with a cleaner way of doing this since, if the child class performs anything in its constructor, I will have to always check if a value was returned.

```
anotherObject = function(foo, bar) {
  var possibleCacheHit = myObject.call(this, foo, bar);
  if (possibleCacheHit) return possibleCacheHit;

  // Do stuff
};
```

Comment: What is the implementation of `.find`? Note that two objects are never equal if constructed separately, which might be the reason `.find` doesn't give a result: `{} !== {}` yields `true`.

Comment: It loops through the objects and compares the values (non-recursively) with the provided object, disqualifying objects with each pass.

Comment: I see, but what is "compares" exactly? I'm asking because `==`/`===` will fail when comparing an existing object with a newly created one, regardless of their contents.

Comment: It compares each value in the object, not the objects themselves. So, if both objects have a `param1` key, the comparison is `obj1.param1 == obj2.param1`. If it comes back as false, the object is disqualified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've learned that the `new` keyword means that I cannot use a `return` statement.

Lucky you, [that's not true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6491067/139010). Provided that you return a **non-null object reference** (see the linked answer for the specifics), the `new` operator will actually let you do what you want.

Comment: Isn't JavaScript just `****`ing _awesome_

Comment: Ah, so I was being clever. :3 It turns out that the issue I was having was actually related to inheritance from this object and not this object, itself. I'll detail it in the question as an update.

Answer (score 3):

Just don't use the new keyword, or at least don't use it outside your caching function

```
var getObject = function(param, param2) {
  var context, cacheHit, obj;
  context = { param1: param1, param2: param2 };
  cacheHit = this.cache.find(context);
  if (cacheHit) {
    return cacheHit
  }

  obj = new myObject(param1, param2); 
  this.cache.save(obj, context);
  return obj;
}
```

Later:

```
var someObj = getObject("a","b");
```

would return an instance of myObject from the cache, if one exists, or create a new one.

Comment: This is another good suggestion, but it _is_ possible to use `new` as the OP originally had it.

Comment: Certainly, but there's often no need to use `new` in javascript.  Many people coming from a Java background instinctively use it for the creation of every object regardless of whether there is any real need for it.  See also:   http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/13/javascript-we-hardly-new-ya/

Comment: I don't disagree, but there are counter-arguments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/383503/139010 and  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6375304/139010

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of situations in which the use of `new` is the best way to do things.